# How to set Date limit in days?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have been trying to set a time limit for a certain form to not function past a specified date in a month, but I have been unsuccessful so far.

I am working with a low-code windows interface software that does the majority of the actual coding in the background but since it has some limitations I need to code this Date limit in myself.

The best thing I reached after looking around was this:

```
DateTime temp = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 15);
```

And I would add a rule in the program that the date shouldn't be higher than the above.
But for some reason it doesn't work giving me an "; expected" error (in line 1 char 29).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-7.0

Comment: The error is not in this line (besides the first `DateTime` has a casing issue). The error should tell you the exact line and column number.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want the form to open past a specific date, or that you don't want it to open past a particular day each month?

Comment: What does "low-code windows interface software that does the majority of the actual coding in the background" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity its a software that does the actual coding part of programming for you, and you only use the software interface to make your Objects, functions, process's, and rules.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I don't want it to open after a specific day in each month.

Comment: @ChriPf Added the error details.

Comment: @user20506645 - I'm sorry, but what does "its a software that does the actual coding part of programming for you, and you only use the software interface to make your Objects functions process's and rules." mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't know how to explain it better than this tbh, probably this type of software has a proper name but I don't how they are referred to, here we call it SystemCreator, Sorry if my explanations are not clear enough.

Comment: @user20506645 - Your question isn't clear. When I run the code you've posted it runs perfectly well. It isn't the cause of your problem. So, your question isn't clear, the code you've posted runs correctly, but you've described an error that clearly is in a different part of your code. I think it is up to you to try to describe the problem more clearly and to provide us with a [mcve] that **demonstrates the actual problem you're experiencing**.

Comment: This is a terrible question. We have two answers trying to do date comparisons, one that tries to tackle the apparent syntax error, but none that in any way relate to the mysterious "low-code windows interface software". I feel that the OP has a serious issue to resolve, but there's not enough detail to get to the crux of the matter.

Comment: @Enigmativity Well that's part of the problem as well, it should work, but it does not, most likely the software's fault, and also there's not much else to provide since that is the code I write (all the other things are filled in by the software), also the site suggests moving to chat but i'm a new user so it doesn't allow me to do that, in anycase thanks for spending the time to read my question and look at my problem.

Comment: @user20506645 - Please read [ask]. That should help with what to change in your question. I've asked for a [mcve] - that means giving us the steps required to create a project using the libraries you're using, and the step to write the code that gives your error. You can do that. If not, please delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only open the specified form up to and including the 15th of the month:

```cs
if (DateTime.Now.Day <= 15)
{
    myForm.Show();
}
```

You can obviously change the operator and/or value to change the way it works. The important point is the `Day` property of the `DateTime` value representing the current date.

Comment: Thank you! 
Your answer helped me to find the solution!
Again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code. you have to use `AddDays` method.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime pastTime = now.AddDays(-15);
DateTime futureTime = now.AddDays(15);
```

It will give you backdate if you provide a negative value.

you also have a typo in your code, the correct DataType is DateTime.

you can comparisons as you have for int, and doubles.

```
if(now < pastTime)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error:

> "; expected" error (in line 1 char 29).

You're missing a ending semi-colon, probably in a line above or below.

Tip: try to name variables well with meaning especially in anything-but-code (ABC) environments:

```
DateTime avoidReservedKeyWords = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 15);
```